# Determining if a BigInteger is Prime in Java

Tags: java, primes, biginteger, binary-search, square-root

I am trying hands on validation of whether a **BigInteger** number entered is a **Prime Number** or not!

But, it is running fine for smaller numbers like **13,31**,but it yields error in the case of **15**;by declaring it as a Prime. I am unable to figure-out the mistake,probably it is hidden in the **squareroot() method** approach involving **binary-search**!

Please view the code and help me point out the mistake!!!

**Calling code :-**

```
boolean p=prime(BigInteger.valueOf(15));
    System.out.println("P="+p);
```

**Called code :-**

```
public static boolean prime(BigInteger bi2){
    if(bi2.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(2)) || bi2.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(3)))
    {
     return true;   
    }
    BigInteger bi,bin;
    bin=squareroot(bi2);
    for(bi=BigInteger.valueOf(2);bi.compareTo(bin)<=0;bi=bi.add(ONE)){
        if(bi2.mod(bi).equals(ZERO))
           return false; 
        else continue;  
    }
    return true;
}


public static BigInteger squareroot(BigInteger bi){
    BigInteger low,high,mid=ZERO,two;
    low=ONE;
    high=bi;
    two=BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    while(low.compareTo(high)<0)
    {
        mid =(BigInteger)(low.add(high)).divide(two);
        //System.out.println("Low-Mid-High="+low+" "+mid+" "+high);
        if(mid.multiply(mid).compareTo(bi)==0)
            return mid;
        if(mid.multiply(mid).compareTo(bi)>0)
            high = mid.subtract(ONE);
        else if(mid.multiply(mid).compareTo(bi)<0)
            low = mid.add(ONE);
    }
    return mid;
}
```

Comment: I assume part of the challenge here is to implement all of the methods from scratch? Hence the square root implementation?

Comment: I strongly suggest stepping through this with a debugger.  I believe you'll find the problem in seconds.

Comment: The square root of 15 (and most numbers) is not an integer, so your square root function is not going to be able to find a correct answer. For example, for 15 it returns a square root of 2.

Comment: @Evan Knowles -No,prime() method is itself involving the square-root() method;but,I firmly believe that the error is with the square-root() determining method

Comment: If you suspect there is a bug in squareroot(), you may run a small function to verify it first. As far as I can see, the way you handle the return value (mid) is not correct. If the while loop is not executed, the return value is ZERO.

Comment: @EvanKnowles -Then why it is correctly determining the prime probability of 13 and 31 exact? I disagree with you.

Comment: @shekhar - He's right.  Believe him.

Comment: @DankeXie -Actually,this binary-search method approximately determines the nearest square-root integer in small time;hence I have used it.I have tried this thing earlier,got success in case of int's but having problem with the BigInteger's!

Comment: No, @shekhar, try running 15 through your `squareroot` function.  It returns 2, no matter whom you believe.

Comment: Don't you think it's a bit rude to contradict the two people who have correctly pointed out your error?

Comment: @DavidWallace -I know it doesn't work;I have myself tried earlier. I am not showing any rudeness,I am as polite as much as I can, but you people are not helping me with the code. I know you are right,but;help me correcting the code by suggesting another approach to find squareroot() rather than pointing out my mistake.

Comment: They are doing *exactly* what you asked them to do. From your question: "Please view the code and **help me point out the mistake!!!**" If you would listen to the advice being given to you you would (probably) have a working algorithm by now.

Comment: Oh,my way of questioning was incorrect,I apologise for the same. Sorry ALL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you return `mid` from `squareroot` without reevaluating it as `(low + high) / 2`.  This causes it to return the midpoint of the *previous* iteration of the algorithm; which is nearly always wrong.

The effect of this is that you sometimes miss some of the prime factors.  In the case of 15, because the `squareroot` returns 2, you miss finding 3 as a prime factor.  In the cases of 13 and 31, there are no prime factors for you to miss, so you get the correct result.

Comment: As per you,what I must try out??? I have learnt that binary-search method for evaluating square-root in this way is fine enough!!!Please elaborate to me somewhat more.

Comment: My answer explains what you have to do.

Comment: Is thsi fine :-return low.add(high).divide(two);

Comment: @shekhar Why don't you try it out?

Comment: Why that way was wrong(incorrect/ and why this is fine? Means,generally I have seen people that they code the binary-search() in this way,wasn't it serving my purpose? Kindly elaborate,I am a bit confused,just because of last step correction!

Comment: @shekhar Try breaking out a pencil and piece of paper and try the two variants for yourself.